# Need to download file on website from command line

Tags: batch-file, wget

I have a link on my website that when clicked dynamically creates a csv file and downloads the file.  I need a way to do this in a batch file so that the file can be downloaded automatically (via task scheduler).  I have played around with wget but I can't get the file.  Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What's the issue? Is there a proxy?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm using wget correctly, but while the link (when clicked on) automatically starts the download, I never get that file.  Only been playing with wget for about 2 days now so I might be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

bitsadmin.exe /transfer "Job Name" downloadUrl destination

If you are using Windows 7 then use same command in Power Shell

Note:
downloadUrl : It is the download url from referred website

destination : It is path of the file where we need to download it.

Answer (score 0):

I use it as follows:

```
#plain wget
wget "http://blah.com:8080/etc/myjar.jar"

#wget but skirting proxy settings
wget --no-proxy "http://blah.com:8080/etc/myjar.jar"
```

Or to download to a specific filename (perhaps to enable consistent naming in scripts):

```
wget -O myjar.jar --no-proxy "http://blah.com:8080/etc/myjar1.jar"
```

If you're having issues, ensure wget logging is on and possibly debug (which will be augmented with your logging):

```
# additional logging
wget -o myjar1.jar.log "http://blah.com:8080/etcetcetc/myjar1.jar"

#debug (if wget was compiled with debug symbols only!)
wget -o myjar1.jar.log -d "http://blah.com:8080/etc/myjar1.jar"
```

Additional checks you may need to do if still no success:

- Can you ping the target host?
- Can you "see" the target file in a browser?
- Is the target file actually on the server?